# Make multiple httpService requests in NestJs

Tags: typescript, axios, rxjs, nestjs, endpoint

I am using NestJs `@nestjs/axios HttpModule` to make a POST request to the controller below:

```
@Controller('api')
export class ApiController {
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

    @Post()
    async acceptAllRequest(@Body() data: string) {
        return this.apiService.executeAllRequest(data);
    }
}
```

The data passed to the controller above containing URL that I want to pass to the service to GET those URL endpoint and return as a single response:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

    async executeAllRequest(data: string): Promise<any> {
        // convert the data string into json object
        // have an array of URL that I want to GET and return as single response
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing so? I came across using `rxjs` forkjoin but I'm unable to return it as a single response. I need more guidance from you guys, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you want all of these requests to happen sequentially, or in parallel?

Comment: If it's okay, I would love to learn both sequential & parallel ways

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Write this code in service.ts

        async findOne(_id: number): Promise<any> {
          const new_req = await this.yourRepository.findOne({id: _id});
          return {
            StatusCode: HttpStatus.CREATED,
            message: "",
            result: new_req
          }

//and then write this code on your controller.ts

//For Get single request

  @Get('/:id')
  getSinglRequest(
    @Param('id') _id: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.yourService.findOne(_id);
  }
```